# Cloudformation template to create a role for SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a role with embedded policy using cloudformation template :

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Resources": {
  "SQSRole": {
     "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
     "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
           "Version" : "2012-10-17",
           "Statement": [ {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                 "Service": [ "sqs.amazonaws.com" ]
              },
              "Action": [
                    "SQS:SendMessage",
                    "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
                    "SQS:DeleteMessage",
                    "SQS:GetQueueUrl"
                ]
           } ]
        },
        "Path": "/"
        }
  },
  "RootInstanceProfile": {
     "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
     "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [ {
           "Ref": "SQSRole"
        } ]
     }
  }
}
}
```

It gives an error " Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"sqs.amazonaws.com".

I also tried by replacing exact URL of SQS queue : "SERVICE":"sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/710161973367/CFI-Trace"

Still it gives same error. Not sure what service to specify for sqs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create an IAM role to be assumed by an EC2 instance, you should use this instead:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "SQSRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "SqsAccess",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "1",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "SQS:SendMessage",
                    "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
                    "SQS:DeleteMessage",
                    "SQS:GetQueueUrl"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "*"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "RootInstanceProfile": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "SQSRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the service that will assume your IAM role is now `ec2.amazonaws.com`. Also, the EC2 service is now only allowed to assume your IAM role (via `sts:AssumeRole`). Finally, all your `sqs:*` Actions have been moved into the IAM Role's `Policies` attribute.