# How to create an SQS queue with cloudformation/SAM that works with lambdas created with SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I am creating lambdas from the AWS SAM, mostly they are working well but I am not sure how to grant permission for these lambda's to be triggered by SQS. Whenever I build/package/deploy I am trying to manually add an SQS trigger from the console and I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when creating the trigger: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException
```

I fully realize that it would be ideal to create the SQS with SAM as well, however I can't find decent guides, specifically about how to build yaml files for deploying with. I wondered if this error meant I need to add a policy to the template.yaml before the build/package/deploy. So I added the following policies to the yaml under Resources:MyFunction:Properties:policies:

```
- SQSSendMessagePolicy:
    QueueName: "*"
- SQSPollerPolicy:
    QueueName: "*"
```

I got these from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/examples/2016-10-31/policy_templates/all_policy_templates.yaml) but I can't see a 'receive message from SQS' policy, I'm unsure where else to get one? Or if this is even the problem?

I also tried to add the following to the yaml:

```
  Events:
    MySQSEvent:
      Type: SQS
      Properties:
        Queue: 
          !GetAtt arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:my_arn.my_queue
        BatchSize: 10
```

However this gives me the following error when I try to deploy:

```
Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:my_arn
```

I have tried looking around for a guide to set up SQS through cloudformation but decent guides seem very elusive. The ones that are around seem overly verbose and complicated making them unsuitable for new users.

All I want to achieve is pass a list of events to an SQS (perhaps with a lambda) which will then queue another lambda to receive those events in batches of 10 (around 20,000 total). I need to be able to do this with SAM is the only caveat. I appreciate making lambdas on the console would make this a great deal easier but its not appropriate for version control.

So far I have looked at the following and can't see an obvious solution, the information seems not quite right to apply to my use case; [SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430768/cloudformation-template-to-create-a-role-for-sqs), [SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995717/aws-cloudformation-template-how-to-configure-lambda-with-a-sqs-queue-to-pick-t), [aws alter stack tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/working-with-templates-cfn-designer-walkthrough-updatebasicwebserver.html), [aws cloudformation templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-guide.html), [dzone tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source-to-aws-lambda-a-deep), [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html).

Would really appreciate any pointers/help/how-to-guides/full working solutions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Events part should be like this

```
Events:
MySQSEvent:
  Type: SQS
  Properties:
    Queue: !GetAtt QUEUE_NAME.Arn
```

Where QUEUE_NAME is the logical name of your SQS Queue in the Cloud Formation template

Comment: Thanks for your help, I now have a new error though: "Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: resource QUEUE_NAME does not support attribute type arn in Fn::GetAtt"

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your SQS Queue and Lambda Function?

Comment: Finally found the error! The naming is very fussy! I had used a standard CamelCase name for my projects queue and thought nothing of it but for some reason "DbfToEaLambdaQueue" doesn't work but "MySqsQueue" is fine. Just posting in case anyone else gets stuck on this! Here is the regex the autogenerated arn must satisfy: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z0-9-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+:([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1})?:(\d{12})?:(.*) Thanks for the help!